# Dead code warning in while loop with 2 if's

Tags: java, dead-code

I can't see why Eclipse gives me a dead code warning for the code in the second if condition:

```
 boolean frameErreicht = false;
  while (!frameErreicht) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line.matches("@\\d*")) {
            reader.mark(reader.getLineNumber() - 1);
            reader.setLineNumber(reader.getLineNumber() - 1);
            frameErreicht = true;
        }
        if (line == null)
            throw new IOException("Keine Angaben zu Frames im Eingabestrom");
    }
```

The jdoc of the readLine() method of LinenumberReader says that it will return `null` if the end of the stream is reached, so if the match is not found throughout the whole text (`line == null`) it should throw an exception.
But what's wrong?

Comment: Is it because you're checking line.matches? It can't be null when it hits the lower line as that access will cause a throw? Move the null check further up before the call to matches.

Comment: In other words, you haven't ever run it? Why asking before running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If line had been null, `line.matches("@\\d*")` would have thrown a NullPointerException

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Its dead since you previously dereferenced the pointer 'line' in line #4 which guarantees that it is NOT NULL or else you would get NullPointerException.

Comment: Please just vote up the existing answer if you think it's a good answer rather than posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
boolean found = false;
String line = null;
while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
    if (line.matches("@\\d*")) {
        reader.mark(reader.getLineNumber() - 1);
        reader.setLineNumber(reader.getLineNumber() - 1);
        found=true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found) throw new IOException("Keine Angaben zu Frames im Eingabestrom");
```

And you are not doing this check at each line...

This code shouldn't return any dead code...

Comment: Why are you removing OP's intent to throw an `IOException`? The solution is rather to just swap the if's.